# How to configure IntelliJ IDEA correctly to process Android Annotations?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-annotations

How to configure IntelliJ IDEA correctly to process annotations?

Using the maven target `processor:process` works fine, but how do I process without using the maven target in IntelliJ IDEA (using it's Annotation Processing preferences)?

Under IntelliJ's preferences / Annotation Processors, I have the following setting:
"`Enable annotation processing`" is checked, with option "`Obtain processors from project classpath`"

I leave the "`Annotation Processors`" section empty, since it should be found through the classpath automatically I assume.
Under processed module I select my Android module and '`target/generated-sources/apt`' as the '`Generated Sources Directory Name`'.

In my project structure, I have the module dependencies "`Maven: com.googlecode.androidannotations:androidannotations:2.6`" and "`Maven: com.googlecode.androidannotations:androidannotations:api:2.6`" set so that I have the processor in my classpath.

But building the project doesn't process the annotations, and instead I get a warning '`Annotation processing without compilation requested but no processors were found.`'

And if I try to set the Annotation Processor manually to '`com.googlecode.androidannotations.AndroidAnnotationProcessor`' and choosing '`/path/to/libs/androidannotations-2.6-api.jar`' as the path to the processor, I'm getting the error "Annotation processor '`com.googlecode.androidannotations.AndroidAnnotationProcessor`' not found" when trying to build the project.

This is my config in screenshots: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/841/intellijaa.png/

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I still haven't gotten it to work using `"Obtain processors from project classpath"`, but it's working now when selecting the path/jar to the processor manually.

I had actually tried that before but my mistake was that I had selected the AA-api.jar instead of the regular AA.jar.

Thanks to Dave, who gave a hint via screenshot on the AA google groups:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/androidannotations/PnAWuSQHkhg

Comment: Did you figure out why the "Obtain processors from project classpath" doesn't work?

Comment: No, meanwhile v12 is out anyway. But there are some additional issue with Android Annotations. Hoping for a fix. But regarding your question: no, haven't looked further into it, since the approach as mentioned in by reply works for me.